# Can I pass a variable to an Android app from a link in an email?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a service that users register for, and part of the registration process requires an email confirmation. There are three ways a user might sign up for the service. On the web, using an iPhone app, or using an Android device.

When I send them the email to confirm their registration, I can include links to complete the registration, and to make the process easier on the user, I can attach their username and a verification code which will then be automatically placed in a form.

In the case of the HTML link, it looks like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://mysite.com/confirmation.html?verification=XXXXXXXXX&username=larry">Complete verification on the web</a>
```

I can get the app to open on the iPhone by making a link to a PHP script:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://mysite.com/iphoneopen.php?verification=XXXXXXXXX&username=larry">complete your verification with the iPhone app</a>
```

And then in the PHP script I have this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=myappname://?verification=XXXXXXXXX&username=larry"/>
```

What code do I use on the Android so that when a user gets the email on their phone (probably with the GMail app), they can click on a link and they will be taken directly to the app? And how do I include variables in that link?

I am using Adobe Phonegap Build for my Android app, so it is built with Javascript and HTML. As a result, I do not know what "intents filters" are. Please take that into consideration when answering. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: You need a webservice that will response the username and verification code when the android app make a request to your webservice then you need to parse the response. You can request using KSOAP2 or depends of what webservice you will make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, you need to add the following `XML` as a child of your `Activity`, which will add an *Intent Filter* (you don't need to know anything more than that):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mysite.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then, in your main `Java` file, where you call a line like this:

```
super.loadUrl(“file:///android_asset/www/index.html”);
```

add the following code (after the line above):

```
try {
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    String data = uri.getSchemeSpecificPart();//this will set data to //mysite.com/iphoneopen.php?verification=XXXXXXXXX&username=larry
    if (data != null) {
        String[] vars = data.split("?");
        vars = vars[1].split("&");
        String verification = vars[0].split("=")[1];
        String username = vars[1].split("=")[1];
        //TODO: handle verification and username from here.
    }
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how stuff works with `Phonegap` etc., but using pure `Android`, when your app will open, your `Activity` will be started actually by an `Intent`, so you can use `getIntent().getUri()`, and you'll actually get the url that have started the app. You can then extract the query params from there.

Comment: Thanks for this information. This describes how I can use variables passed to the app, but unless I'm not seeing it, it doesn't describe how to structure the link in the email, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: the same that you would pass variables in any `URL`. same as the `HTML` link.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that is quite the case. If you look at the format of the URL for linking to the Android app in the example in my question, there is no clear place to put a variable.

Comment: what you have placed there... it is an `IntentFilter`. that will be triggered when the user opens a URL with the provided scheme://host mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm just not following what you are saying. I don't have the same level of expertise you do, so your terminology and assumed knowledge is beyond me. I don't know what an intent filter is, or what scheme and host mapping are. I can't parse any of what you are saying into a concept of how I write out the link I include in my email.